# Bringing a classifier to production

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I've saved my classifier pipeline using  joblib:

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, ngram_range=(1, 3))
pac_clf = PassiveAggressiveClassifier(C=1)
vec_clf = Pipeline([('vectorizer', vec), ('pac', pac_clf)])
vec_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
joblib.dump(vec_clf, 'class.pkl', compress=9)
```

Now i'm trying to use it in a production env:

```
def classify(title):

  #load classifier and predict
  classifier = joblib.load('class.pkl')

  #vectorize/transform the new title then predict
  vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, ngram_range=(1, 3))
  X_test = vectorizer.transform(title)
  predict = classifier.predict(X_test)
  return predict
```

The error i'm getting is: ValueError: Vocabulary wasn't fitted or is empty!
I guess i should load the Vocabulary from te joblid but i can't get it to work

Comment: What error do you get when storing / loading the vectorizer?

Comment: i did not get a error when loading, the problem is now solved. Than you for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just replace:

```
  #load classifier and predict
  classifier = joblib.load('class.pkl')

  #vectorize/transform the new title then predict
  vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5, ngram_range=(1, 3))
  X_test = vectorizer.transform(title)
  predict = classifier.predict(X_test)
  return predict
```

by:

```
  # load the saved pipeline that includes both the vectorizer
  # and the classifier and predict
  classifier = joblib.load('class.pkl')
  predict = classifier.predict(X_test)
  return predict
```

`class.pkl` includes the full pipeline, there is no need to create a new vectorizer instance. As the error message says you need to reuse the vectorizer that was trained in the first place because the feature mapping from token (string ngrams) to column index is saved in the vectorizer itself. This mapping is named the "vocabulary".

Comment: Thank you @ogrisel works great ... in addition just found this helpful blog about optimizing my classifier [link](http://blog.scrapinghub.com/2014/03/26/optimizing-memory-usage-of-scikit-learn-models-using-succinct-tries/)