# how to reuse the classifier in the pickled pipeline in sklearn?

Tags: nlp, scikit-learn

I have read the answer in another post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25794131/4566048

the classifier is pickled, how about the TfidfVectorizer? how can I use it from the pickled pipeline? since I need it to transform my feature vector, I still need to use it right?

Answer (score 2):

After some digging around, I seem to have solved the problem. I will answer my own question here in case it can help anyone with same doubt in the future.
I found that only save the classifier is not enough, CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer which are used to do the feature vector extraction need to be saved as well for it to work.
hope that helps!